# C# declaring array in class with not constant type variable through constructor

Tags: c#, arrays, class, constructor

I'm not sure if the title is clear so, I'm declaring an array in class, but the problem is that when I want to create a class the size of array might be different and by that I want to tell the size of array to the class by the constructor. Example.

```
    const short DeckSize;
    private char[,] Deck = new char[DeckSize, 2];
    public HandDeck(short Size)
    {
        DeckSize = Size;
    }
```

So the problem here is that array has to be a constant or static as my compiler says.

I found something about readonly attribute and tried to change code to this

```
readonly short DeckSize;
private char[,] Deck = new char[DeckSize, 2];

public HandDeck(short Size)
{
     DeckSize = Size;
}
```

And it works (probably), but now the declaration doesn't meet the requirements. And at this point I am out of ideas. Any great suggestions here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    private readonly short DeckSize;
    private readonly char[,] Deck;
    public HandDeck(short Size)
    {
        DeckSize = Size;
        Deck  = new char[DeckSize, 2];
    }
```

Comment: Oh great, that was quite easy. Thanks for fast reply.